# VB.NET Change progressbar value from BackgroundWorker?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 progress-bars. Now I do some other things in my code, which takes time to execute thus the need to use a `backgroundworker`. I don't have much of an idea how to use `backgroundworker`. The rest of my code that I haven't included here executes just fine, but the `progressbar` values does not change, nor their texts. How would I achieve that?

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim LM As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
    Dim LM_SW As RegistryKey = LM.OpenSubKey("Software")
    Dim LM_MS As RegistryKey = LM_SW.OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
    Dim LM_Win As RegistryKey = LM_MS.OpenSubKey("Windows")
    Dim LM_CV As RegistryKey = LM_Win.OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
    Dim AppPaths As RegistryKey = LM_CV.OpenSubKey("App Paths")
    Dim NrOfFiles1 As Integer = AppPaths.SubKeyCount

    ProgressBar2.Maximum = NrOfFiles1
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

    For Each FormatString As String In AppPaths.GetSubKeyNames()
        ProgressBar2.Value += 1 / NrOfFiles1
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1 * ProgressBar2.Value / 100 / 10
        ProgressBar1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & "%"
        ProgressBar2.Text = ProgressBar2.Value & "%"
    Next

    ProgressBar2.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Yesh, that did the job, was much more simple than I thought :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the ProgressChanged event of the Backgroundworker.
In your DoWork method, call

```
BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Percentage)
```

Where Percentage is an integer value

Then in the ProgressChanged event you can manipulate your progress bar.

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork

     Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

     '''YOUR OTHER CODE
     worker.ReportProgress(PERCENTAGE)
     '''YOUR OTHER CODE

    End Sub 

    ' This event handler updates the progress. 
    Private Sub backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,         ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
        ProgressBar1.Value  = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
```